# Trying to get and parse session variable (xml string) in jstl

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a jsp servlet that queries a database and returns an xml string then sets it as a session attribute using

```
session.setAttribute("directoryInfo", xmlString);
```

I'm then trying to get the attribute and parse it using jstl with this code:

```
function renderResults(){

    var xmlString = <%=(String) session.getAttribute("directoryInfo")%>
    document.write("<ul class ='list'>");
    <x:parse xml="${xmlString}" var="output"/>

    <x:forEach select="$output/person">
    <x:set var="uid" select="string($output/person/@uid)"/>
    document.write("<li>uid: " + $uid + "</li>");
    </x:forEach>
}
```

When I deploy it on tomcat, I immediately get the error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jstl:; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.

I think it has something to do with the way I'm passing the variable.

Note: @uid is an attribute within the "person" tag in the xml string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use JavaScript variable in server-side code.
You should be able do

```
<x:parse xml="${directoryInfo}" var="output"/>
```

or to specifically target session you can do

```
<x:parse xml="${sessionScope.directoryInfo}" var="output"/>
```

JavaScript means nothing to server-side languages, they just treat is as generic text.

Comment: Same problem. I *think* it might be trying to run the jstl when the page loads. I want it to run after I post form info, run the query based on the info (in the jsp), and return the xml string. I thought wrapping the jstl in a javascript function then using jquery to call the function after posting the form data would work, but no dice.

Comment: @jordaniac89 what you can do is to use `var xmlString = "<%=(String) session.getAttribute("directoryInfo")%>"` as you did before (just notice the quotes), and then use Javascript to parse the `xmlString`. Again, you need to learn the difference between server-side and client -side code. Javascript can only run in the client browser, and there is no JSTL at this point. The page has been generated and sent to client. Client then only deals with static HTML